# Class using XmlReader is not grabbing XML data as expected

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, datarow

I have a class in my app that is not transforming my XML data as expected.

### XML Data

Below is an excerpt of the XML. The file size can be between 2 GB and 3 GB, and the data is a representation of Mutual Funds. Each Fund usually has managers associated with it, but it's possible that there are none listed. A Fund in the data can have multiple ManagerDetail nodes or can have no ManagerDetail nodes. Each manager can have multiple CollegeEducation nodes or no CollegeEducation nodes.

```
<MutualFund>
<ManagerList>
<ManagerDetail>
    <ManagerRole>M</ManagerRole>
    <ManagerId>7394</ManagerId>
    <ManagerTenure>3.67</ManagerTenure>
    <StartDate>2011-09-30</StartDate>
    <OwnershipLevel>6</OwnershipLevel>
    <GivenName>Stephen</GivenName>
    <MiddleName>M.</MiddleName>
    <FamilyName>Kane</FamilyName>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <Certifications>
        <CertificationName>CFA</CertificationName>
    </Certifications>
    <CollegeEducations>
        <CollegeEducation>
            <School>University of Chicago</School>
            <Year>1990</Year>
            <Degree>M.B.A.</Degree>
        </CollegeEducation>
        <CollegeEducation>
            <School>University of California - Berkeley</School>
            <Year>1985</Year>
            <Degree>B.S.</Degree>
            <Major>Business</Major>
        </CollegeEducation>
    </CollegeEducations>
</ManagerDetail>
</ManagerList>
</MutualFund>
```

### C# Class

I've created a class that is called within a BackgroundWorker instance in another form. This class places the above data into the following table:

```
public static DataTable dtManagersEducation = new DataTable();
dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("ManagerId");
dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Institution");
dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("DegreeType");
dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Emphasis");
dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Year");
```

The method that places the XML data is set up like this. Basically, I have certain points where DataRows are created and completed, and certain XML data is to be placed into the available row as the data is read.

```
public static void Read(MainForm mf, XmlReader xml)
{
    mainForm = mf;
    xmlReader = xml;

    while (xmlReader.Read() && mainForm.continueProcess)
    {
        if (xmlReader.Name == "CollegeEducation")
        {
            if (nodeIsElement())
            {
                drManagersEducation = dtManagersEducation.NewRow();
                drManagersEducation["ManagerId"] = currentManager.morningstarManagerId;
            }
            else if (nodeIsEndElement())
            {
                dtManagersEducation.Rows.Add(drManagersEducation);
                drManagersEducation = null;
            }
        }
        else if (xmlReader.Name == "School")
        {
            if (nodeIsElement() && drManagersEducation != null)
            {
                string value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                drManagersEducation["Institution"] = value;
            }
        }
        else if (xmlReader.Name == "Year")
        {
            if (nodeIsElement() && drManagersEducation != null)
            {
                string value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                drManagersEducation["Year"] = value;
            }
        }
        else if (xmlReader.Name == "Degree")
        {
            if (nodeIsElement() && drManagersEducation != null)
            {
                string value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                drManagersEducation["DegreeType"] = value;
            }
        }
        else if (xmlReader.Name == "Major")
        {
            if (nodeIsElement() && drManagersEducation != null)
            {
                string value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                drManagersEducation["Emphasis"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool nodeIsElement()
{
    return xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element;
}

private static bool nodeIsEndElement()
{
    return xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement;
}
```

The result ends up with no data in the Emphasis or Year columns, which as you can see above, there are instances (plenty) that have data in these fields.

```
ManagerId    Institution        DegreeType   Emphasis    Year

5807         Yale University    M.S.    
9336         Yale University        
7227         Yale University    M.S.
```

Would you all happen to have some insight into what is going on?

Thanks

### Edit: Answer

My sample XML data listed above has indented spaces, but the actual data that I was running through the XmlReader did not. As dbc has shown below, adding a variable `bool readNext` fixed my issues. As I understand it, if `readNext` is set to false when `ReadElementContentAsString()` is called, the XmlReader will not call `Read()` since my while loop condition now contains `(!readNext || xmlReader.Read())`. This prevents the two methods `ReadElementContentAsString()` and `Read()` to be called right after another, and thus, it will not skip over data.

Thanks to dbc!

Comment: Have you tried reducing this to a shorter example, and stepping through it in a debugger to work out what's going on?

Comment: Sure, I'll work on creating a simpler example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that the method [`XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162529%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) moves the reader past the end element tag.  If you then do `xmlReader.Read()` unconditionally right afterwards, the node immediately after the end element tag will be *skipped*.  In the XML shown in your question, the node immediately after your end element tags is *whitespace*, so the bug isn't reproducible with your question.  But if I strip the indentation (and hopefully your 2+GB XML file has no indentation), the bug becomes reproducible.

Also, in your question, I don't see where you actually read the `<ManagerId>7394</ManagerId>` tag.  Instead you just take it from `currentManager.morningstarManagerId` (an undefined global variable).  I reckon that's a typo in your question, and in your actual code you read this somewhere.

Here's a version of your method that fixes these problems and can be compiled and tested standalone:

```
    public static DataTable Read(XmlReader xmlReader, Func<bool> continueProcess)
    {
        DataTable dtManagersEducation = new DataTable();
        dtManagersEducation.TableName = "ManagersEducation";

        dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("ManagerId");
        dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Institution");
        dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("DegreeType");
        dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Emphasis");
        dtManagersEducation.Columns.Add("Year");

        bool inManagerDetail = false;
        string managerId = null;
        DataRow drManagersEducation = null;

        bool readNext = true;
        while ((!readNext || xmlReader.Read()) && continueProcess())
        {
            readNext = true;
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (!xmlReader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    if (xmlReader.Name == "ManagerDetail")
                    {
                        inManagerDetail = true;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "ManagerId")
                    {
                        var value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        readNext = false;
                        if (inManagerDetail)
                            managerId = value;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "School")
                    {
                        var value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        readNext = false;
                        if (drManagersEducation != null)
                            drManagersEducation["Institution"] = value;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "Year")
                    {
                        var value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        readNext = false;
                        if (drManagersEducation != null)
                            drManagersEducation["Year"] = value;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "Degree")
                    {
                        var value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        readNext = false;
                        if (drManagersEducation != null)
                            drManagersEducation["DegreeType"] = value;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "Major")
                    {
                        var value = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        readNext = false;
                        if (drManagersEducation != null)
                            drManagersEducation["Emphasis"] = value;
                    }
                    else if (xmlReader.Name == "CollegeEducation")
                    {
                        if (managerId != null)
                        {
                            drManagersEducation = dtManagersEducation.NewRow();
                            drManagersEducation["ManagerId"] = managerId;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                if (xmlReader.Name == "ManagerDetail")
                {
                    inManagerDetail = false;
                    managerId = null;
                }
                else if (xmlReader.Name == "CollegeEducation")
                {
                    if (drManagersEducation != null)
                        dtManagersEducation.Rows.Add(drManagersEducation);
                    drManagersEducation = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return dtManagersEducation;
    }
```

Comment: That was exactly it! After introducing `bool readNext` to my code, my class now performs as expected. Thanks!